# How to build an if condition in shell to check whether curl succeeded?

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, curl

I am running a cURL command in Linux that is returning 200.

```
curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "http://google.com" -o /dev/null
```

However, If I run the same as below, I get "Fail" as output:

```
if [ "curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "http://google.com" -o /dev/null" == "200" ]; then echo "Success"; else echo "Fail"; fi
```

Please let me know that what is wrong here?

Comment: `[` is not part of `if` syntax. Use `if curl`, not `if [ curl`

Comment: ...also, `==` is not valid `test` syntax per the POSIX standard; `=` is the only string comparison operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using command substitution correctly.  Rewrite it this way:

```
if [ "$(curl -sL -w '%{http_code}' http://google.com -o /dev/null)" = "200" ]; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

As Charles suggested, you can further simplify this with `--fail` option, as long as you are looking for a success or failure:

```
if curl -sL --fail http://google.com -o /dev/null; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

Comment: Why not `curl --fail`, and let `curl` be responsible for a nonzero exit status on non-successful (non-200-series) results?

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ $(curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" "http://google.com" -o /dev/null) = 200 ]; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

Check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst